# New Relic MySQL Server not showing up

Tags: java, mysql, unix, newrelic-platform

I've installed New Relic on two servers, both are working fine.
I've installed the MySQL plugin, exactly the same way on both, but only 1 is appearing in New Relic.
As far as I can tell the configuration on both is identical (apart from the MySQL user of course).
When I start the plugin the only feedback I get is `INFO: New Relic monitor started`, there's no indication of any errors (even if I deliberately put in invalid MySQL user details). There's also nothing really to see in the log files at `/var/log/newrelic/`, no indication of any errors happening.
I've changed `loggin.properties` to uncomment the following lines, as described in the file, run it a few times, but I still can't see any 'newrelic.log' anywhere:

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = newrelic.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append = true
```

Any idea's what the problem might be, or how else I can find problems?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check that the user that you are starting the plugin as (probably `newrelic`) has permission to write to the log file in `/var/log/newrelic/`. That was the cause of a similar issue I had with another New Relic plugin.

Comment: I know it's not ideal as a proper solution, but I'm currently launching it as root with `nohup java -jar newrelic_mysql_plugin-1.0.5.jar &`, and just to be sure given `/var/log/newrelic/` 0777, so it should definitely be able to write files there, but still no log output.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can cause an issue with this is If the server names are identical, if they are they will both report to the same plugin component which will make it look like only one is running.

Comment: I thought that might be the issue, but I've tried a few different names and it made no difference. Do you know if there's any other ways it identifies the server that I could try changing?

Answer (score 0):

This thread may be a lttle old, but I was searching for the exact same situation and finally found where my errors were being logged.

I was having the same problem with a single server, even running the plugin as root.

I finally found the errors were being logged in a 'nohup.out' file in the directory I was running the jar file from.  That is where the connection errors (permissions) were being logged for me.